# Acquire ground coordinates of target while doing aerial survey (airplane or helicopter)

Tags: gps, 3d, aerial-triangulation

**The Problem:**

Each year I board a small airplane and look for diseased individual trees while flying transects over the forest I help manage. The current method for marking a tree's location is manually creating a point in a GIS on a tablet by matching actual ground features with the aerial imagery basemap in tablet. It's not very accurate.

**The Question:**

Is there a tool that I can point at a ground target (a tree in my case) that will return an accurate pitch and azimuth *in a moving airplane*?  My plan would be to pair that pitch/azimuth information with the GPS coordinates of the airplane (handheld GPS or embedded in the tool) and lay that offset over a digital elevation model to acquire a ground coordinate for my target.

**What I've Already Explored:**

TruPulse 360 laser rangefinders: A rep at the company said that their rangefinders would not work from inside a moving airplane.
Drone/UAV-based surveys: A UAV is too slow compared to an airplane, although a good lat/long can be captured by hovering directly over a target and snapping a picture with the camera pointed straight down.

Comment: Is it feasible to collect geolocated orthophotos? If so, would you be able to located the diseased trees on those photos afterward? That would give you the gps coordinates of each tree.

Comment: I have a feeling that for some targets (trees) the horizontal distance from the airplane might be too far to capture an orthophoto - too oblique. We would have to fly a much tighter (slower) grid.

Comment: I thought maybe the US Forest Service would have some information on this, but I'm only finding outdated guidance documents on their website. Maybe if you reach out to the contact people for their forest health aerial survey and aviation programs they'll have better suggestions. https://www.fs.fed.us/foresthealth/aviation/aerialsurvey.shtml https://www.fs.fed.us/foresthealth/fhm/dm/maps/aerial.shtml

Comment: @csk, Thanks! Good thought! I made some calls to USFS forest health folks.  I'll respond to this if come across something helpful from them.

Comment: TruPulse 360s definitely work in the air (at least a model I used 5+ years ago). There are also automated systems used in aerial distance surveys that allow you to take instantaneous heading and down-angle readings.

Comment: @Simbamangu, Thanks!  Just to be clear, did you use the TruPulse360 in an airplane (versus a helicopter)? Also, I've done some searching for aerial distance survey equipment like you mentioned and keep coming up empty.  If you have any leads for me to follow, I'd love to chase them down.  Thanks again!